# Android device doesn't appear in Visual Studio 2017 as deployment option

Tags: deployment, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, device

I am creating Xamarin.Android project in Visual Studio 2017 Community edition. My device is ZTE Blade A452, my computer's operating system is Windows 7. I downloaded the driver for ZTE Blade, run its `.exe`, and followed the steps from the following link:

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb#Drivers

Then I followed the steps from `Install USB Drivers` part from the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/set-up-device-for-development

In both cases a message said something like: "Your driver has been updated succesfully" but Visual Studio 2017 still doesn't show the device name as a deployment option. I have looked at questions on internet related to that topic but every answer said something different and complex to do. And as the answers had to do with system administration(installing, uninstaling things on Windows) rather than with programming(which is the thing I control more) I was worried to take any actions fearing that I would make things worse and irreversible. My question is, is there more simple solution to my problem? My other question is why deployment on a real device has to be so dificult, a part from programming I have to do things related to Windows etc. ?

Comment: I use ADB over Wifi most time to avoid USB cable/driver issues. After activating ADB over Wifi in dev options, run adb connect IP:5555 and it shows up in VS2017

Comment: Once I deployed the app throught wifi but deployment was 2 times slower than the deployment trought cable if I remember well. So there is no easy solution to my deployment trought cable? 2 years ago I did it on Windows 10 only by doing the steps from `Enable Debugging on the Device` from the second link and I don't remember having to install drivers etc. Is it possible me to have these problems because I develop on Windows 7?